# Get href of loop in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm scraping web urls from a website and don't know what I'm doing wrong...Im new to JS.

I want to get the href elements of the a .relative tags. Elements variable is working, but $(this) is not. It will not say anything as an error, but will not put anything into the console.log

```
elements = $("a .relative").each(function() {
    links = $(this).href;
    console.log(links);
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your selector seems funny, are you sure it's not `a.relative` instead of `a .relative`?

Also use `$(this).attr('href')` instead of `$(this).href`

Try running:

```
$("a.relative").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).href` will return undefined.

you need to use `.attr()` to get/set attribute value:

```
$(this).attr('href');
```

**Update: To get all href in array**

```
$("a .relative").map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('href');
}).get();
```

Comment: well your `links` does not seem like an array. When you do `$(this).attr('href')`, that assigns a string

Comment: have you checked the console? it should log all the href values.

Comment: Ok this answer is correct, Also, I had a space between the a and the class in the jquery selector which returned undefined. :( Stupid

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be 
`links = $(this).attr('href');`

This will return the attribute `href` from the object `$('a.relative')`

I assume you're looking for anchors with the class `relative`? And not elements with the class `relative` inside an anchor (since you have a space between the `a` and `.relative`)

Answer (score 0):

A space between element and class will look for *descendent* elements with that class, so the jQuery selector `a .relative` will find any element with the class `.relative` that is a descendant of any `a` element.

You probably want `a` elements *with* the class `relative` in which case you want no space in your selector.

```
$("a.relative").each(function() {
  ....
});
```